# Is it a good practice to use WCF simplified configuration?

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0, web-config, .net-4.5

I was looking at sine WCF code using simplified configuration and I was wondering if this is a good practice or better said, what are the pros and cons of going through this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally think its good. Much of the configuration (pre-4 days) is set to default values anyway and given the complexities of WCF configuration, removing these default values and behaviours is a plus. Less is more in this instance. As long as everyone understands what the defaults are, simplifying your config allows you to focus on how you have extended the configuration to suit your environment, making those customisations more visible. There is less [xml] code to read and maintaining which is also a good thing. The only downside I can think of is that you have to be familiar with the configuration schema and know what the defaults are and how they behave.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to go for different approaches depending on the type of solution i'm building. If it is a complex enterprise multi-tier solution that will be managed, developed and troubleshooted by different people and companies during its life-cycle i rather spend some extra time using the *SvcConfigEditor* and make sure some default values are explicit set. My experience is that it really will simplify troubleshooting and performance-tuning in these environments.

But in small and simple solutions i sometimes go for the simplified configuration as it can save some valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified configuration is great if the defaults are acceptable... and they usually are.

If you are working on an Enterprise app you should keep in mind:

- Some WCF default values will vary depending on .NET version or the number of processors in the server. They are likely to change yet again with the next .NET version. In this case change isn't necessarily a bad thing... the WCF team picks the default values for a reason. But they will change without you knowing it.
- The default throttling values are fairly conservative and may limit how much load you can process long before you hit your hardware's capacity. This was especially true in .NET 3.5 and earlier.